# CloudBees pipeline failed due error on "influxdb.exceptions.RequestEntityTooLargeException"

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, influxdb, cloudbees

I am a newbie here and I would like to seek advices/help if anyone had any idea(s) what is wrong for the issue i had encountered at below.

In CloudBees, I have these 2 jobs under this main folder. Example:

ROBOTS (main folder) > DEV_TEST (sub-folder) > TEST_Robot_FrontEnd
ROBOTS (main folder) > DEV_TEST (sub-folder) > TEST_Robot_BackEnd

This pipeline **TEST_Robot_FrontEnd** had been up to #99 build ran over the past few months and average size for the output.xml generated is 158MB. This pipeline will use the output.xml and published the results to the Grafana (influxdb).

This is similar for pipeline **TEST_Robot_BackEnd** had been up to #67 build ran over the past few months and average size for the output.xml generated is 26MB. This pipeline will use the output.xml and published the results to the Grafana (influxdb).

Recently, this pipeline **TEST_Robot_FrontEnd** started to have this issue and failed unable to publish data to Grafana (influxdb).
*Caused: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: jenkinsci.plugins.influxdb.InfluxReportException: com.influxdb.exceptions.RequestEntityTooLargeException*

There is no issue at all for this pipeline **TEST_Robot_BackEnd** and it is still working fine.

*Note : The reason why we have main-folder with sub-folder created in the CloudBees because we have other pipelines belong to other team usage. It is only our pipeline is having this EntityTooLarge issue due do daily regression usage.  *

After much investigation, I still had no clue what is the cause of this issue.

It is strange, I moved this pipeline TEST_Robot_FrontEnd to a different new folder and it did not have the influxdb.exceptions.RequestEntityTooLargeException issue at all. Example:

ROBOTS (main folder) > DEV_NEW_TEST (sub-folder) > TEST_Robot_FrontEnd

Currently, this is our way of workaround but still I would like to know what is the issue(s) here if you are able to advice. Many2 Thanks.